# "Take on responsibility" vs. "take up responsibilty"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, phrasal-verbs, collocation

> I now have to take *_* additional responsibility.

Are both *on* and *up* grammatically correct? Is there a difference in meaning? When to use which one?

Comment: I (AmE) would only ever say "take on", and this is substantially more prevalent in Google searches, but it seems that indeed both are used.

Comment: Rochele, please [edit] your question to correct it rather than posting comments. You might also be interested in our sister site [English Language Learning](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) and I suggest you read our [help] to understand what this site's scope is.

Answer (score 3):

Take **on**

> to begin to perform or deal with :  undertake

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20on)